# VBA code that retrieves website table but table name doesn't update

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a mixture of VBA and a macro to retrieve a website table, but it doesn't update the table name when it runs and has to be manually changed before running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub NZXMarket()
'
' NZXMarket Macro
' Daily list of NZX market
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0 (4)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.nzx.com/markets/NZSX""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Code"", type text}, {""Company"", type text}, {""Price"", Currency.Type}, {""Change"", type text}, {""Volume"", type number}, {""Value"", Currency.Type}, {""Capitalisation"", Currency.Type}, {""Pe" & _
        "rcentage Change"", type number}, {""Type"", type text}, {""Green Bond"", type logical}, {""Trade Count"", Int64.Type}, {""Currency Code"", type text}, {""Market Capitalisation"", Currency.Type}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""Green Bond"", ""Currency Code""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0 (2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0 (2)]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0__4"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
        MsgBox "Download Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). You didn't ask a question yet (see alse [ask]). • What does *"has to be manually changed before running"* mean? • What is wrong with your code, what does it do versus what do you expect? Which errors do you get and where?

Comment: I' m not sure what you want, but I think you should use PowerQuery. With PQ you can get the table with a few mouse clicks and update it with about one mouse click. https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/the-complete-guide-to-power-query/